# VB.Net and MySQL (how to make installer that automatically planted)

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I want to ask about making application with VB.Net that use MySQL as its DMBS
when you build the program,and running the application on other PC that PC does
not have the database. So how do I make an installer or .exe file that can plant
the database every time it runs on other PC? I heard that it will involve .dll file, but I'm not sure of it.
I hope you guys understand my way to explain the problem.

Comment: MySql needs to be installed on the client PC, then you need have a script that rebuild your database schema, distribute the Connector Dll (MySql.Data.Dll) and modify your connection string. If you have a scenario with a single user and no need to share the database file over the lan you could try to use a file based database like SQLite, SQL Server Compact or also the MS-Access engine and distribute your database as a file (In any case a library will be required to be distributed along with your application)

Comment: yeah i mean like file based database, so SQLite can provide that? i look into google and not sure about the keyword. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes with SQLite you just deploy your database, install the SQLite libraries, fix you connectionstring and you are done. The same happens with SQL Server Compact, SQL Server LocalDB or Access. However Access has some problem if the version of Office installed is bit incompatible with your app

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a same problem. Solution I did is to make a connection string in txt and load on start

```
Sub SConnect()
    Dim path As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
    Dim fileReader As String
    fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(path & "\conn.txt")
    Dim xx As String

    xx = fileReader
    If myconn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then myconn.Close()
    Dim MyConString As String = xx
    myconn.ConnectionString = MyConString
    myconn.Open()
    mycomm.Connection = myconn

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

txt file is as under

DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};SERVER=IP Address;DATABASE=DB Name;UID=User ID ;PASSWORD=123456;Character Set=utf8;OPTION=3;